# Avoid performSegue multiple times

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ios7, segue

I have more than 20+ buttons in my application. For these buttons if I click twice it performSegue twice and opens the viewcontroller twice, throughout my application in swift iOS?

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toViewController", sender: nil)
```

Comment: After the button is tapped disable that button immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a tag to each button and define an array of segues

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier:segues[sender.tag], sender: nil)
```

or simply make the button the source of the segue , if you're not willing to override `prepareForSegue`

Comment: if I click the button twice, it performSegue twice and opens the viewcontroller twice

Answer (score 0):

- You could declare a property

  ```
  var isSegueEnabled = true
  ```
- Then implement the method to control whether the segue should be performed

  ```
  func shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier identifier: String, sender: Any?) -> Bool {
      return isSegueEnabled
  }
  ```
- In `prepare(for segue` set the property to `false`

  ```
  isSegueEnabled = false
  ```
- At some point after the presented view controller has been dismissed set `isSegueEnabled` back to `true`